# How to apply system themes on Flutter apps in Kubuntu?

Tags: themes, 23.10, flutter

I am running a flutter app in Kubuntu (it is directly compiled, and not containerized in snap or flatpak). It uses a theme that resembles the Adwaita theme. I have set Arc to be the default theme for both Qt and GTK apps in KDE system settings.

How to apply the Arc theme in flutter apps? At least, can I make the titlebar use the system theme?

Comment: What do you mean by "It uses the Adwaita theme"? It probably has a theme which looks similar to Adwaita, but I don't think Flutter themes have anything to do with GTK themes.

Comment: I agree with you. It uses a theme that resembles Adwaita